# Datediff function in Sql does not give accurate hour value

Tags: sql

```
start date: 2012-05-29 08:30:00.000
end date: 2012-05-29 15:00:00.000

DATEDIFF(hour,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
```

This gives me 7 hours, but it is actually 6.30

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want accuracy, you should use this approach

```
declare @start_date datetime, @end_Date datetime
select @start_date='2012-05-29 08:30:00.000', @end_date='2012-05-29 15:00:00.000'
select datediff(minute,@start_date ,@end_Date)/60.0
```

Comment: (DATEDIFF(minute,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)/60.0) as [Hour]
gives 10.000000. And how can we show it like 10.0 ?

Comment: I solve that problem: cast((DATEDIFF(minute,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)/60.0) as float)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @start_date datetime, @end_Date datetime
select @start_date='2012-05-29 08:30:00.000'
select @end_date='2012-05-29 15:00:00.000'
select cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_date,@end_Date)/60 as varchar)
+'.'+CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_date,@end_Date)%60 as varchar)
```

this will give you result as you want

6.30

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference in minutes and then convert the minutes into hours..

Answer (score 0):

As you are using "hour" datepart it gives you a rounded value. Use minutes, it will return 390min, is the correct answer. Then transform to hours.

[This link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/10/21/sql-server-datediff-accuracy-of-various-dateparts/) should help you to have a better understanding of what are you doing with this statement. Check MSDN too for [DATEDIFF sintaxis and uses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Sample code:

```
    DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME='2012-05-29 08:30:00.000'
    DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME='2012-05-29 15:00:00.000'

     SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDateTime,@EndDateTime)/60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The datediff function just counts crossings of the units specified, not the actual time between the two values. So in your case the "hour" crossings between the times are 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15, which totals 7 "hour" crossings. So, to get more precision, you want to use a unit of time in your datediff function that represents the precision you need, then convert that to hours.

Answer (score 0):

Code to Find Exact Time in difference in hours and minutes,

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME='2015-10-03 19:49:37.000' 
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME='2015-10-05 07:31:28.000'
DECLARE @HourOfDiff INT=CAST(datediff(minute,@STARTDATE ,@ENDDATE)/60.0 AS INT)
DECLARE @MinofDiff INT=DATEDIFF(mi,@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE)-(@HourOfDiff*60)
SELECT CAST(@HourOfDiff AS VARCHAR(10))+':'+ CAST(@MinofDiff  AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following working examples -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("mi",StartDate,EndDate)/60 AS TimeInHours FROM dbo.JobData<BR>

SELECT DATEDIFF("ss",StartDate,EndDate)/3600 AS TimeInHours FROM dbo.JobData
```

**For Hours Sql Server does not produce correct/accurate data, so count it in Minutes or seconds and then convert to Hours.**