# SQL Select Subtract Date Time with Date Time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have 2 different fields from a table and both have same format of timestamp.

`7/18/2012 10:19:48 AM` 

 and 
`7/18/2012 10:20:46 AM`

How can I subtract two timestamp to get the duration in time.

Comment: What is the data type of the field?  String or datetime?

Comment: tell you truth, I don't know but when under where in SQL query I have `To_Date(to_chat(Table.field, 'DD-MON-YYY'))` if this makes any sense.

Comment: @Mogli - Why do you convert the field to a char and then to a date? Can you show exactly what is in the field ***before*** you apply `to_date(to_char())`? *(Perhaps rounding a datetime to a date?)*  Also, you really should find out what the data-type ***really*** is, including asking your colleagues for help.

Comment: To_Date(Table.field, 'DD-MON-YYY')

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Your error and comments look like Oracle.

Comment: @Dems I just ran a test query without `to_date(to_chat())` I don't think it made any difference, it shows `7/18/2012 10:20:46 AM`

Comment: Have a look:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465355/datediff-function-in-sql-does-not-give-accurate-hour-value

Comment: @TimLehner - The OP originally had the `Oracle` tag, then deleted it.  But I have no idea why.

Comment: @Mogli . . . if I recall, to_char() is only in Oracle and Postgres.  You should find out which database and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I wish I could as such question to my boss, he might think I mess around with production server so I avoid such questions. hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (firstDateColumn - secondDateColumn) * 24 * 60 difference_in_minutes
FROM yourtable
```

If the dates are string then convert them first:

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(firstDateColumn, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM') - 
        TO_DATE(secondDateColumn, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM')) * 
        24 * 60 difference_in_minutes
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: `Oracle` tag and `MSDN` link?  I'm not going to downvote this answer, but other people might.  Unless you update/delete it...

Comment: Thanks I removed Oracel tag, I tried the code you showed, I get this error `One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier at System.Data.`

Comment: @Mogli - ***WHY*** did you remove the `Oracle` tag??? Your error message proves that this is Oracle, put the tag back. This answer and link are for MS SQL Server, and don't work for Oracle - That's why having the tag in there is important; there are different answers for different RDBMSes...  *[This was the case until an edit was made to the answer...]*

Comment: @Dems Thank you, your first solution worked, but it shows `0.96666666666..` instead if I can show in hours like `0:01` Thanks.. Fyi for others second one shows this error `ORA-01818: 'HH24' precludes use of meridian indicator at System.`